# Recovering a frame field from its connection forms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-forms, differential, connections

I have a faced a research problem where I would need to recover a frame field given its connection forms. More precisely, I begin with an orthonormal frame field (given by data) in $\Re^3$ written as
$$
\mathbf F=\begin{pmatrix}\vec f_1\\\vec f_2\\\vec f_3\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\vec f_i:\Re^3\rightarrow\Re^3$ are vectors fields with $\vec f_i\cdot\vec f_j=\delta_{ij}$, and $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. I then obtain the connection forms
$$
\omega_{ij}=\text{d}\vec f_i\cdot\vec f_j,
$$
which yields
$$
\text{d}\mathbf F=\Omega\mathbf F
$$
where $\Omega=[\omega_{ij}]\in\Re^{3\times3}$ is the skew-symmetric matrix of connection forms.

In my application, I then proceed by computing the interior product of the 1-forms $\omega_{ij}$ onto the frame fields themselves (the Christoffel symbols), i.e., I compute
$$
\omega_{ijk}\equiv\omega_{ij}\langle\vec f_k\rangle\in\Re
$$
where $\langle\cdot\rangle$ denotes the standard interior product for forms. I thus obtain 9 different measurements at each point, i.e., $\omega_{121},\omega_{122},\omega_{123},\omega_{131},\omega_{132},\omega_{133},\omega_{231},\omega_{232},\omega_{232}$, each of which has a very precise meaning in the application at hand.

Now, I would like to do the converse, i.e., **I would like to solve for $\mathbf F$ given the list of interior contractions** $\omega_{121},\omega_{122},\omega_{123},\omega_{131},\omega_{132},\omega_{133},\omega_{231},\omega_{232},\omega_{232}$.

The Frobenius theorem states the unique existence of $\mathbf F$ in the neighborhood of $0$ if we set $\mathbf F(0)=I$ and if the following are satisfied:
$$
\Omega=\text{d}(F)F^{-1}
$$
$$
\text{d}\Omega-\Omega^2=0.
$$
but I'm unsure about where to start. Would anybody have a suggestion on how to approach this problem? Is there a formal name to what I'm trying to do?

Perhaps a better way to formulate the problem is to enumerate the frame axis differentials directly:
\begin{align}
\text{d}\vec f_1&=\omega_{12}\vec f_2+\omega_{13}\vec f_3\\
\text{d}\vec f_2&=-\omega_{12}\vec f_1+\omega_{23}\vec f_3\\
\text{d}\vec f_3&=-\omega_{13}\vec f_1-\omega_{23}\vec f_2.
\end{align}

Writing the direction of contraction as 
$$\vec v=\sum_i^3(\vec v\cdot\vec f_i)\vec f_i=\sum_i^3v_i\vec f_i$$
we obtain
\begin{aligned}
\text{d}\vec f_1\langle\vec v\rangle&=\left(\sum_i^3v_i\omega_{12i}\right)\vec f_2+\left(\sum_i^3v_i\omega_{13i}\right)\vec f_3\\
\text{d}\vec f_2\langle\vec v\rangle&=-\left(\sum_i^3v_i\omega_{12i}\right)\vec f_1+\left(\sum_i^3v_i\omega_{13i}\right)\vec f_3\\
\text{d}\vec f_3\langle\vec v\rangle&=-\left(\sum_i^3v_i\omega_{13i}\right)\vec f_1-\left(\sum_i^3v_i\omega_{23i}\right)\vec f_2.
\end{aligned}

Which gives us three coupled differential equations to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You are in fact asking how to integrate the following vector differential equation:
$$
df = \Omega f,
$$

where $f$ is, say, vector $f_1$ (to get $f_2$ and $f_3$ just use different initial conditions). If I understand correctly, you would like to find a matrix function $M$ such that:
$$
f(x) = M(x)f(0).
$$

On $\Bbb{R}^3$, the first equation is integrable if and only if both members are exact forms. So, if and only if:
$$
0=d(\Omega f) = d\Omega\, f - \omega\,df = d\Omega\,f - \Omega(\Omega\,f) = (d\Omega -\Omega^2)f.
$$

This is what Frobenius's formula means. Now, $\Bbb{R}^3$ is flat, and it should be no trouble checking that this condition is indeed satisfied.

So how do you find $M$ from $\Omega$? What you do is called either [product integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral) or [ordered exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential) (it is a good exercise to check that they are in fact equivalent).

Intuitively, consider a curve $t\mapsto \gamma(t)$ on $\Bbb{R}^3$. Since we have seen that our equation is integrable, only the endpoints matter. 
Suppose have our vectors of our frame field at $\gamma(0)$. We want to transport them, using our connection form matrix $\Omega$, to vectors at $\gamma(t)$.

Now after a small time $\Delta t$, our vector will have *slightly* rotated, so:
$$
f(\Delta t) \approx \big( 1 + \Omega\,\Delta t \big)f(0).
$$

Therefore, our vector at time $t$ will be the composition of "many" such small rotations:
$$
f(t) \approx \big( 1 + \Omega(t_n)\,\Delta t \big)\big( 1 + \Omega(t_{n-1})\,\Delta t \big)...\big( 1 + \Omega(t_1)\,\Delta t \big)f(0).
$$

If $\Delta t$ is small enough, we can write a [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential):
$$
\big( 1 + \Omega(t)\,\Delta t \big) \approx \exp\big( \Omega(t)\,\Delta t \big).
$$

So we get:
$$
f(t) \approx \exp\big( \Omega(t_n)\,\Delta t \big)...\exp\big(\Omega(t_1)\,\Delta t \big)f(0).
$$

The matrix exponential has the rule $e^Ae^B=e^{A+B}$ *only* if $A$ and $B$ commute. So if the $\Omega_{t_i}$ all commute with each other, the product of exponentials becomes an exponential of a sum:
$$
f(t) \approx \exp\big( \Omega(t_n)\,\Delta t +...+ \Omega(t_1)\,\Delta t \big)f(0),
$$

so in the limit we get exactly an exponential of an integral:
$$
f(t) \approx \exp\bigg( \int_0^t \Omega(t)\,dt \bigg)f(0).
$$

This is, for example, what happens in a $2$-dimensional space. In 3 dimensions, in general, the $\Omega(t_i)$ do *not* commute with each other, and the product above does not turn into an ordinary integral. 
What you get is a special generalization of the exponential, called the [ordered exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential). Click on the link above to see how to work with it.

So in the end:
$$
M(x) = Pexp\bigg( \int_0^x \Omega \bigg)f(0).
$$
In physics, it is used to reconstruct the global rotation after some time, when you have the angular velocity expressed as a function of $t$ (can you see why the problem is very similar to ours?).

Comment: Thanks. I understand your motivation but should we really treat "f" as a vector in your first equation? This would lead to decoupled solutions for all three vector fields, which shouldn't be (see the three equations at the bottom of the original question).

Comment: I don't understand. Why decoupled? $\Omega$ is a matrix...

Comment: $\Omega$ is indeed a matrix but the way I wrote it, it is applied to a matrix $\mathbf F$ which contains $\vec f_i$'s where each $\vec f_i$ is treated as a symbol, and not a vector. The true explicit representation of the frame field differential has to be written as three coupled equations (see bottom of my initial post). Does this make sense?

Comment: If $f_x,f_y,f_z$ are the component of the vector $f_1$, then $df_x=\omega_{xy}f_y-\omega_{xz}f_z$, and so on.